# Garbage accessToken using facebook login

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, zend-framework, facebook-login

I am using facebook login using oauth. Sometime I am getting proper accessToken or sometime this kind of garbage values in accessToken

```
{"source":"uni","s":"s","p":{"z":"0","c":"0","i":"287"},"r":  {"z":"1","c":"15239"},"node_id":"23.57.77.12"}.
```

Because of that my next requests to graph API fails. What is that thing and How do I handle this??

I have multiple domains ex. www.example.com, www.example12.com, www.example22.com etc.
I have created app for www.example.com on facebook and using it for all domains using the window.postmessage:

homepage.php (When user click on facebook login button):

```
       if(!window.addEventListener){
            window.attachEvent("onclick", processFacebookLogin);
        }
        else{
            window.addEventListener("message", processFacebookLogin, false);
        }

        var width = 500;
        var height = 500;

        var left = ((window.innerWidth / 2) - (width / 2)) + window.screenLeft;
        var top = ((window.innerHeight / 2) - (height / 2)) + window.screenTop;

        winObj = window.open("http://www.example.com/fb-login?currentDomain=www.example12.com", "fbwindow", "height="+width+",width="+height+",top="+top+",left="+left);

        function processFacebookLogin(e) {
            winObj.close();
            if(e.data != "error" && e.data != "missing_param"){
                accessToken = e.data;
                $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    url: "UrlToProcessFacebookLogin",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: 
                    {
                        "medium" :"facebook",
                        "accessToken" : accessToken
                    },
                    success: function(data)
                    {   
                        //redirect to some another url
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

child window url page contains the following code fbLoginController.php:
The above window.open contains the indexAction url of fbLoginController (I am using Zend Framework):

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $communityDomain = preg_replace('#^https?://#', '', $_GET['community']);

    $fbLoginUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/v1.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=FbAppClientId&scope=AllRequiredScopes&auth_type=rerequest&return_scopes=true&display=popup&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/fb-login/fb-response?community=".$communityDomain;

        $this->_redirect($fbLoginUrl);

    exit;
}

public function fbResponseAction()
{
    $arrParams  = $this->_getAllParams();

    $code = $arrParams['code'];
    $communityDomain = $arrParams['community'];
    $grantedScopes = $arrParams['granted_scopes'];
    $error = $arrParams['error'];

    if(!empty($error))
    {
        echo "<script>window.opener.postMessage('error', 'http://".$communityDomain."');</script>";
        exit;
    }

    if(empty($communityDomain) || empty($grantedScopes))
    {
        echo "<script>window.opener.postMessage('missing_param', 'http://".$communityDomain."');</script>";
        exit;
    }

    $curlUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/oauth/access_token?client_id=FbAppClientId&client_secret=FbAppClientSecret&code=" . $code . "&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/fb-login/fb-response?community=" . $communityDomain;


    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curlUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 5000);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);

    $curlResponse   = curl_exec($ch);
    $curlError      = curl_error($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    parse_str($curlResponse,$parsedStr);

    echo "<script>window.opener.postMessage('".$parsedStr['access_token']."', 'http://".$communityDomain."');</script>";

    exit;
}
```

for proper understanding I have put each and every line of code in this question.

Comment: Looks like you’re assuming that you will always get a successful result from the code exchange endpoint … time to implement some proper error control, I’d say.

Comment: @CBroe Thanx. I will do that. But have you seen the response from FB oauth. Can you pls tell me why I am getting this kind of access token. 
And this happens only sometime otherwise i get proper access token. Now I dont understand what do i do about this. Today I got this access token: `MessageEvent {ports: Array[0], data: "{"source":"dsa","version":"r16","s":"l","r":{"z":"…":"0","i":"77"},"request_signature":"1541207642"}", source: Window, lastEventId: "", origin: "http://transact-eu.cedexis.com"…}`